# Basic PostgreSQL Questions - Do I need another user?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I installed postgreSQL by default with apt-get and I believe it has automatically added a user for me called "postgres".

1. I only have one database that I want to sort on postgres, so is
   there any point creating another user account for this database or
   should I just keep with the one which is installed with postgreSQL
   "postgres"?
2. The user account postgres which is made for me, is it given some
   kind of default password? Is it recommended that I put in my own
   password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I misinterpreted the question, the OP is asking about internal users, not system users

### Original Answer: System users for running servers

Most services running on a linux box are given their own independent user, as a standard security practice.  In the off-chance that the postgreSQL server was compromised -- either you made a mistake, or there was a vulnerability in postgresql, or whatever -- the attacker can only gain access to the resources allowed to the user running the postgresql server.  If that user is root, you lose the machine.  If that user is your user, you lose not quite as much.  If that user is `postgres`, which only has minimal access to anything.. you lose the database, and that's all.

So:

1. You merely need a single user for the postgreSQL server, regardless of what, exactly, that server process is hosting.  If (it sounds like one was) a user was created for you automatically, you're all set with this step.  If you need to make one manually (sounds like you don't), you would also have to change the permissions so that the new user can access only what it needs to.
2. That account very possibly cannot be directly logged into; if it has a password at all it's a lot of random data.  In order to use the account, you need to start out as root, and then voluntarily "downgrade" yourself to `postgres`.  In the case of the server, root starts the server "under the name of" postgres.  I would advise leaving it alone.

### Second Answer: Database users

Once you have a server running, the server will keep its own set of users, for the purposes of accessing the database.  The simplest architecture you could use there is just having a base user with full permissions do everything.  While this works, it is not advised if you are hosting this externally.  A more preferable solution is to have a set of users, similar to how the OS is set up: a bunch of users to do specific tasks, and one admin user to rule them all.  That said:

1. You don't have to, but if you are going to host this anywhere (if you're not just using it for personal things, and it's world-accessible), I would advise extra users with limited permissions.
2. http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-admin/2001-10/msg00192.php

   > There is no password by default; create one with ALTER USER.
   >
   > Passwords do not take effect unless pg_hba.conf is set up to use them.  If
   >   it is, and you have not assigned a password to postgres, you will not be
   >   able to connect as postgres.

Comment: re 1): I don't think he is talking about a Linux user, but a Postgres user.

Comment: Haven't used postgres, but I'd expect it's default internal username would be something like 'root'.  postgres sounds like the name of the linux user that hosts the server process to me.

Comment: Yes, see I'm getting a bit confused now. I was actually talking about a database user not a system user. Does postgresql install via apt-get create a system user AND a database user?

Comment: OK, misinterpreted then.  `cat /etc/passwd` and see if there's a new system user too check.

Comment: @zebediah49 The default "admin" user is named postgres (usually the OS user gets the same name so it is a bit confusing).

Comment: There is a user postgres in cat /etc/passwd. Are we saying that there is also a postgreSQL user called postgres automatically created?

Comment: And..if so, is a good idea to use that user as the owner of my only database or should I create a fresh one and leave that admin user blank? EDIT: Just saw your edit, think this might answer my question

Answer (score 1):

re 1)

the default database user that is created during installation is a "superuser" and for the same reason you should not do your daily work as "root", you shouldn't work with a superuser in a DBMS. So the answer is a clear: yes, do create a second user. You can grant that role all privileges on the default database (also called postgres), so that you don't need a second database.

More details on how to create a user and how to grant privileges can be found in the manual:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createuser.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html

re 2)

I don't know Linux that well, but usually you should have been asked for a password during installation. At some point in the installation a new data directory is initialized using the command `initdb` which requires a password to run.

If you don't know the password, you log into the postgres linux account, then you can probably run `psql` without specifying a password. That enables you to reset the database password and create a new user.

More details about users and authentication are in the manual:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/user-manag.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I upvoted but can only pick one.